# cmake ignores dpendency to external library

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, dependencies, external

I'm using an external library for my project. If my project will be build completely linking works fine.

The problem is when the external library would be updated. If I try to build my project again which the updated external library no linking will be done. It seems that it will be ignored that the external library is new than the executable of my project.

In CMakeLists.txt the external library is defined in following way:

```
set(RH_ROOT "../RH")
target_link_directories(OCoM PUBLIC ${RH_ROOT}/build)
target_link_libraries(OCoM RH
```

So, in a short summery. Basically the dependency works find and building the executable is successful. Only an update of the external library is not handle correctly. In this case I expect that cmake would recognize that linking against the newer external library is neccessary.

As additional information: I'm using MinGW, but I quit sure that this is not the problem.

Any ideas to solve the problem?

Regards
Rainer

Comment: "In this case I expect that cmake would recognize that linking against the newer external library is neccessary." - How CMake would recognize that the library file is newer if you never tell CMake about that file? Link directories are passed directly to the linker (with `-L` option), the library name `RH` is passed to the linker too (with `-l` option). So, it is linker who searches the library, not CMake. Instead, pass to the `target_link_libraries` the **full path** of the library file. In that case CMake will know the exact file and will be able to setup dependency from it.

Comment: Thanks, suggested solution works.
I expected that the linker is intellegent enough to look in given target_link_directories for a corresponding file. (any give an error if none or more than one was found)